# Acts_as_paranoid, is_paranoid... Alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm looking for a rails plugin/gem which brings the functionality of marking an ActiveRecord-Model deleted, instead of deleteing it.

Does anybody know, what gems or plugins are up to date? (AAP is out-dated and is_paranoid doesn't appear to be used by the community).

Do you know alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is_paranoid doesn't appear to be used by the community..

http://chadfowler.com/blog/2009/07/08/how-ruby-mixins-work-with-inheritance/ - Just a blog post the other day talking about it. Seems like it solved Chad's problem just fine (as well as lead him to write a post about inheritance and mixins).

Comment: No sorry. Is there a reason that is_paranoid is unusable for your needs?

Comment: No, but didn't found much websites about it... Therefore i thought its not very famouse... however, thank you

Answer (score 7):

It seems even the authors of both acts_as_paranoid and is_paranoid aren't using their respective plugins/gems any more.  Both are using named scopes.

Yeah, it's not automagic or anything, but sometimes being explicit about your intentions is a good thing.

Comment: This.  (I'm the author of is_paranoid.)

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is a more recent gem for this purpose:

**Paranoia** - acts_as_paranoid for Rails 3

https://github.com/radar/paranoia

And another:

https://github.com/JackDanger/permanent_records

Answer (score 1):

How about you just have a `valid:boolean` column/attribute and set it to false when you wish to soft-delete the model? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I would like to do that automatically :)